# Create array from State grouping IDs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, use-context

I'm building a shopping cart, and my cart products array comes from a state. When I press the 'add to cart button, this function occurs(Infos is where the product Infos are):

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
function addToCart() {
   setCart( arr => [...arr, {
     name: infos[id-2].fullName,
     value: infos[id-2].value,
     id: infos[id-2].id
}])}
```

And it's working fine, but I have repeating IDs on the cart array. This has implications on the checkout page and etc. So I need to create a new array from the cart with all the cart items, but excluding the repeated items, something like this:

```
const newCart = [{
   id: cart.id
   name: cart.name
   quantity: '' >times the id occurs on the cart array
   price: cart.value
   totalPrice: cart.value * quantity
}]
```

How can I do so? I'm using context to manage all my states

Comment: What does the value key in cart represent ?

Comment: Does it represent price for that item ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Please be more precise. What do you want to do? Aggregate the quantitiesbased on the Item ID or remove items with duplicate item IDs?

Answer (score 1):

Why put duplicate ids on the cart in first place, You can include one more field in the cart object and update that only.

```
const cart = [{ name: "A", value: 100, id: 1, quantity: 1 }];

function addToCart() {
  const item = infos[id - 2];
  setCart((arr) => {
    const newCart = [...arr];
    const existingItem = newCart.find((i) => i.id === item.id);
    if (existingItem) {
      existingItem.quantity++;
    } else {
      newCart.push({
        name: item.fullName,
        value: item.value,
        id: item.id,
        quantity: 1,
      });
    }
    return newCart;
  });
}
```

Comment: Ty, this solved all my problems!

Comment: If it's not asking too much, how can I add a separate functiont to remove the item from the cart array?